# Magento Backend issues (Extjs)

Tags: magento-1, javascript, error, backend

I have some issues in my backend :

- no product categories
- some buttons not working
- no editor

In firebug console there are several JS errors.

example for the categories page :

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ext-tree.js:237:1907
ReferenceError: Ext is not defined ext-tree-checkbox.js:5:0
ReferenceError: Ext is not defined c96dd103cc157f99e581f95aeebb3f9b:78:4
SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script tiny_mce.js:1:162812
ReferenceError: Ext is not defined
```

Here is my header with all the JS call :

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Nouvelle catégorie / Gérer les catégories / Catégories / Catalogue / Administrateur de Magento</title>
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var BLANK_URL = 'http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/spacer.gif';
    var BASE_URL = 'http://www.xyxyxy.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/eae39fce2c5de59417b756c810cba2fa/';
    var SKIN_URL = 'http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/';
    var FORM_KEY = 'RuD7RnjhQU40pXnv';
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/extjs/resources/css/ytheme-magento.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/prototype/windows/themes/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/custom.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/print.css" media="print">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/menu.css" media="screen, projection">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/extjs/fix-defer-before.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/prototype/window.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/hash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/events.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/grid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/accordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/tools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/uploader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/product.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/extjs/ext-tree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/extjs/fix-defer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/extjs/ext-tree-checkbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/variables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/lib/flex.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/lib/FABridge.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/mage/adminhtml/browser.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/iestyles.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/below_ie7.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/lib/ds-sleight.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/varien/iehover-fix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/ie7.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xyxyxy.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/iestyles.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = BLANK_IMG;
    Ext.UpdateManager.defaults.loadScripts = false;
    Ext.UpdateManager.defaults.disableCaching = true;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xyxyxy.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Fieldset.addToPrefix(1);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA//]]>
</script>
</head>
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: visit link:-http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-external-javascript-css-file-to-magento/

Comment: your `extjs` file make a conflict with `prototype.js`

Comment: thank you. How can I solve it?

Comment: @Alexglvr have you find a solution for this issue?